# Name for reaction producing carbon from CO2

Tags: redox, terminology, catalysis

Some years ago I heard of a reaction where hydrogen could be used to reduce $\ce{CO2}$ to carbon and water, similar to the Sabatier reaction. I believe it also used iron as a catalyst at high temperature. Can anyone remind me of the name of that reaction or correct me if I am mis-remembering the details.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help] if you have any questions about how the site works. Best of luck with your question!

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/915/how-to-convert-carbon-dioxide-into-carbon-and-oxygen

Comment: I since found the answer to my question, it is the Bosch reaction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosch_reaction